# JavaMail with tomcat6 server

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-mail

Iam new to java mail. my requirement is , i need to add email services to my web application that is developing using servlets and my web server is apache tomcat6 ..so any body would help me, how would i go through?

any suggestions appriciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Java Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html) API. Please have a look at tutorial - [Fundamentals of the JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html).

Comment: Thank you for reply..i will go through it